# Minecraft Server Assistance Needed

Tags: wireless-networking, minecraft, gopro

I am a college student who likes to play mine craft with my friends. Unfortunately our laptops are monitored (using DYKnow).

I have a Gopro hero 3 that has inbuilt Wi-Fi. We tried using that to play but we can't access each others game (we can still see it in the multi-player section).

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Which OS are you and your friends using?

Comment: Mainly asking to know if I should point to the windows solution (`netsh wlan set hostednetwork ...`) or a BSD / Linux one.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Firewall exceptions for Minecraft and java are needed.  If you are using windows OS.  Had this same issue setting up a local server for my kids.

Comment: Im using Win8 and my friends Are using win7.

Comment: ok, did you add the exceptions?